# Performance issue - refactor select subqueries which are doing the same joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join

In MySQL, how would you re-write a SELECT query which JOIN SELECT subqueries that are doing almost the same thing.

In my case, I am getting performance issues because in the subqueries, I need to join on the same tables for each subqueries which is an heavy operation.

Consider the below (ugly) example:

```
set @businessdate = '2020-01-24';

Select Daily.*, Monthly.Price, Yearly.Price FROM
# DAILY
(Select @businessdate as BusinessDate, t1.Owner , SUM(t.Price) AS DailyPrice
FROM Table t
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 on ...
INNER JOIN Table1 t1 on ...
where t2.date = @businessdate
GROUP BY t1.Owner) Daily

INNER JOIN
# MONTHLY
(Select SUM(t.Price) AS Price, t1.Owner
FROM Table t
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 on ...
INNER JOIN Table1 t1 on ...
where MONTH(t2.date) = MONTH(@businessdate) and YEAR(t2.date) = YEAR(@businessdate)
GROUP BY t1.Owner) Monthly

INNER JOIN
#YEARLY
(Select SUM(t.Price) AS Price, t1.Owner
FROM Table t
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 on ...
INNER JOIN Table1 t1 on ...
where YEAR(t2.date) = YEAR(@businessdate)
GROUP BY t1.Owner) Yearly
```

The reason is I need the date in my where clause (coming from t2), and one field in my group by coming from t1. I also need to display some fields from t1.

I only need the `SUM(Price)` (the Price from Monthly and Yearly...) so to me it sounds like the joins in subqueries is overkill even if it is working fine (very slow...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use conditional aggregation with a single query:

```
Select
    @businessdate as BusinessDate, ... ,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t2.date = @businessdate THEN t.Price ELSE 0 END) AS DailyPrice,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(t2.date) = MONTH(@businessdate) AND
                  YEAR(t2.date) = YEAR(@businessdate)
             THEN t.Price ELSE 0 END) AS MonthlyPrice,
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(t2.date) = YEAR(@businessdate)
             THEN t.Price ELSE 0 END) AS AnnualPrice
FROM Table t
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 on ...
INNER JOIN Table1 t1 on ...
GROUP BY t1.Owner
```

This at least would allow you to avoid unneeded passes over the joined tables.  Note that your `GROUP BY` clause is invalid as written; the business date is the only valid single column which can be selected, other than the conditional sums.

Comment: This is definitively a more readable solution! Thank you for your answer. Indeed I edited my initial post. I tried to add as less info as possible to make it understandable (and readable...). For some reason, your solution is slower compared to the subqueries. I will need to dig out on my side